# how to configure webstorm 9 to highlight current file?

Tags: webstorm

Just starting to use webstorm 9 , have been using vs.net a lot and missing the 'track item in solution explorer' feature. I would like to see the file highlighted in the project viewer on the left. How can I configure this in webstorm?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Click the little settings gear drop-down in the Project view header and choose "Autoscroll from Source."

Comment: brilliant that is too easy:)

Comment: No default keyboard shortcut?

Comment: In WebStorm 2021.2 this is now named "Always Select Opened File". Not sure in which version this got renamed though

Answer (score 1):

To make it the default behaviour for all (future) projects and not just the current project, there's a plugin from Jetbrains that will enable this.

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7575?pr=

Answer (score 0):

You can also click the three dots icon on the Project panel and check the option `"Always Select Opened File"`.

[image]

[image]